# CakePHP 2.0 Controller render not working all of the time

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a search controller that will look up values and render specific views according to the type of report that should be displayed.  There is a weird thing happening.  When I issue the $this->render the report view is not rendered.  The "catch all" redirect line always is rendered...  Code as follows:

> public function admin_printReport() {
>
> ```
> if (isset($this->request->data['Reports'])) {
>
>     $nons = $this->request->data['Reports'];
>
>     $res = array();
>
>     // lets lookup the noncons.....       
>     foreach ($nons as $dat=>$vdat) {
>
>         // skip the ones that are not checked 
>         if ($vdat == 0) {
>             continue;
>         }
>
>         // this is the temporary array that holds all of the selected report numbers          >             $res[] = $dat;
>
>     }
>
>     $this->loadModel('Noncon');       
>     $this->Noncon->recursion = 0; 
>     $results = $this->Noncon->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Noncon.id'=>$res)));
>     $this->set('results', $results);  
>
>     // lets do the selection now...
>     if (isset($this->request->data['PS'])) {  
>         // Print summary
>         $this->render('summary', 'print');
>     } elseif (isset($this->request->data['PD'])) { 
>         // Print detail 
>         $this->render('detail', 'print');
>     } elseif (isset($this->request->data['PDH'])) { 
>         // Print detail with history 
>         $this->render('detailhistory', 'print');
>     }
> } 
>
> // catch all if the render does not work....
> $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'noncons', 'action'=>'search','admin'=>true));
> ```
>
> }

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out....

for each $this->render, add return.  For example:

> return $this->render('summary', 'print');

Answer (score 0):

I've just add a similar problem.

In a controller, that has an ajax submit, it was not submitting the render.

```
$this->render($viewName, 'ajax');
```

Using return didn't helped.

The problem was that I added

```
$this->render('add');
```

at the end of the controller, although it was not necessary since the controller name is *add* and the autoRender is default (true to automatically render the view with the same name of the controller).

Hope this helps someone else.